# Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, maven, struts2

I have been working on ORM with hibernate using eclipse as my IDE. I use Maven as my build system. In the wake of learning Struts, I was trying to get a hello world working. However, I'm not sure what is the problem and it keeps giving me:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
```

Here is what the folder structure is like:

[image: Project folder structure]

**Pom.xml**: Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/XrNYcty7)

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>wah</display-name>

   <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Menu">
            <result>/menu.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>  

</struts>
```

**Menu.jsp** has a simple hello world text.

Can someone please help me explain why am I getting the **ClassNotFoundException** error. How can I fix it ? What is the recommended **directory structure** for setting up a struts 2 project ?

**EDIT:**

Source code exported in .zip [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/RMduosCJ/wah.html).

Thanks

Comment: Do a Ctrl-T and type `FilterDispatcher`. Does it show any result?

Comment: do you have struts2-core jar file in your class-path?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I added struts2-core as a dependency, to pom.xml using maven. See last entry on the pastebin link.

Comment: What does it show? Where is the class located?

Comment: @m0skit0 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Apart from adding struts2-core in pom, do I have to do anything else ?

Comment: Wow, pretty confusing... That class is the only one that fails? Are you sure that's the exact correct package Eclipse shows? Which path? Try cleaning the project and check the "Build automatically" setting. If this does not work, try setting up the project from zero in a new fresh workspace.

Comment: @brainydexter FilterDispatcher is the entry point of S2 and its in struts2 core.How you are running your application?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I open up menu.jsp, and hit Run > Run on Server. which then gives me a 404. Also, when the tomcat server starts up, it gives me that error (ClassNotFoundException). Am I setting up the pom correctly ? Do I need to add anything else to it ??

Comment: @m0skit0 I know, I'm stumped. I have no clue why it's failing. Can you please check the pom.xml in pastebin to see if I am missing something obvious. In some places, I read, one might need to include something in pom.xml so that it copies some libraries in WEB-INF > lib.

Comment: do a check, inside your .m2 repository, org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher, exist or not, If not do a recompilation with install command.

Comment: @brainydexter: POM is correct as per S2 is concerend

Comment: @subodh couldn't find the file, but jar exists here: \.m2\repository\org\apache\struts\struts2-core\2.3.1.2

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi See my last comment for m0skit0. Since the WEB-INF > lib is empty. Do I need to edit the pom to something else ? Is there a way I can share my code with you guys here ?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi,  Is my folder structure correct ??

Comment: Your folder structure is seems ok, but do one thing copy your WEB-INF folder inside web-app and test it.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Can you please take a look at the source code I uploaded ? Attached a link in the edit. Thanks

Comment: Try adding your struts jar in your tomcat/server/lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is my application folder structure and working fine see[image]

and this is pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tek</groupId>
    <artifactId>marf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Struts 2 Blank Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>2.3.1.2</struts2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.21</version> -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.0.2</version> 

                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/struts.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/example.xml</scanTarget>

                    </scanTargets>
                     <source>1.6</source> 
                    <target>1.6</target> 
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="struts_blank" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>Struts Blank</display-name>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcherr
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

source [here](http://www.struts2.org/tutorials/developing-struts2-applications-using-eclipse-m2eclipse-plugin-and-maven.html)

Comment: Oh, i did a mistake to add pom.xml in folder structure, But it's present inside the main app that marf.

Comment: what is the scanTarget tag in pom.xml ?

Comment: <scanTargets> Is Optional A list of files and directories to periodically scan in addition to those automatically scanned by the plugin

Comment: Can you please take a look at the source code I uploaded ? Attached a link in the edit. Thanks